# Crash/RSOD when binding RN attributes/props to a pure Swift view

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I successfully bridged a Swift view. A simple label that does nothing. I am now trying to make it respond to props.

### Just creating a Swift label without reaction to props works fine

1. Created `SampleView.swift` with following:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit
   import SpreadsheetView

   class SampleView: UIView {

     let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)


       self.label.text = "This is SWIFT"
       self.addSubview(self.label)


       let controller = ViewController();

       self.addSubview(controller.view);
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

   }
   ```
2. Created `SampleViewManager.swift` with following:

   ```
   import Foundation

   @objc(SampleViewManager)
   class SampleViewManager : RCTViewManager {

     override func view() -> UIView! {
       return SampleView();
     }

   }
   ```
3. Created Cocoa Touch Class named `SampleViewModule` (so two files `SampleViewModule.h` and `SampleViewModule.m`:

   - `SampleViewModule.h` I put the following:

     ```
     #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     #import <React/RCTView.h>

     @interface SampleViewModule : RCTView

     @end
     ```
   - `SampleViewModule.m` I put the following:

     ```
     #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
     #import <React/RCTViewManager.h>


     #import "SampleViewModule.h"

     @interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(SampleViewManager, RCTViewManager)

     RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(txt, NSString);

     @end
     ```
4. And of course the objective-c/swift bridging header `ss-Bridging-Header.h`:

   ```
   #import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
   ```

### This part works - usage in react native

So now this works perfectly. It creates a label that says "This is Swift" in React Native I just do

```
import { requireNativeComponent }from 'react-native'
const SampleView = requireNativeComponent('SampleView', null);

// ...

<SampleView />
```

### Now to connect it to a prop `txt` to affect label text I did this:

Only the additions are shown below. The full code of the above files with additions can be seen here in my gist - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/af0285e15cd6dc32b9543e5f9bd8a9c9

1. Added to `SampleView.swift`:

   ```
   func setTxt(txt: NSString?) {
     if txt != nil {
       self.label.text = txt! as String
     }
   }
   ```
2. Added to `SampleViewModule.h`:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *txt;
   ```
3. Added to `SampleViewModule.m`:

   ```
   RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(txt, NSString);
   ```

### Crash on mount

When mounting it with a `txt` attribute like this:

```
<SampleView txt="Hi from React Native" />
```

Is causing `SIGABRT`, here is a screenshot:

[image]

### setState RSOD:

```
    state = {
        txt: undefined
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(()=>this.setState({txt:'rawr'}), 5000);
    }

    // ...

    <SampleView txt={this.state.txt} />
```

Initial `state.txt` is `undefined` so it mounts without error. But when `state.txt` is set to a string, this causes this red screen of death (RSOD) to show after 5 seconds. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

#### May you please help me to set the label

Comment: I know the post is a bit log. But it is very simple. I broke everything down into bite size pieces. I would really appreciate a read. :(